# How to visualize a vaadin web component

Tags: css, vaadin, web-component

1. Follow the vaadin guidence of web component to create a meter:

   ```java
   @Tag("dw-meter")
   @NpmPackage(value = "echarts", version = "5.2.2")
   @JsModule("../node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.js")
   @JsModule("./dwmeter.webcomponent.js")
   public class DwMeter extends Div {

   }
   ```
2. Integrate the meter into a demo application:

   ```java
   DwMeter meter = new DwMeter();
   meter.setWidth("100px");
   meter.setHeight("100px");
   add(meter);
   ```
3. Application is executed successfully, but the meter is not displayed.
4. Trace the web page, Tag <dw-meter> and <canvas> are generated correctly :
   [image: Screenshot of <dw-meter>]
5. Changed Tag <dw-meter> to <div>,  the meter is visible:
   [image: Screenshot of <div>]

My question is how to visualize an user-defined vaadin web component? e.g. <dw-meter>

attached dwmeter.webcomponent.js:

```
import * as ECharts from "echarts";

class dwMeter extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    init(o) {
        // Shadow root
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

        // container
        var container = document.createElement('div');
        shadowRoot.appendChild(container);

        // Garantee all elements are rendered
        setTimeout(function() {

            var myChart = ECharts.init(o);  //container

            myChart.setOption(o.options());

        }, 0);

    }

    options() {
        const gaugeData = [
                {
                  value: 0.25,
                  name: 'pressure',
            title: {
              offsetCenter: ['0%', '90%']
            }
                }
              ];

        var option = {
          series: [
            {
              type: 'gauge',
              min: 0,
              max: 0.25,
              splitNumber: 5,

              progress: {
                show: false,
                width: 5
              },
              axisLine: {
                lineStyle: {
                  width: 5,
                  color: [[1, 'rgba(36,177, 76)']]
                }
              },
              axisTick: {
                show: false
              },
              splitLine: {
                length: -10,
                lineStyle: {
                  width: 5,
                  color: 'rgba(36,177, 76)'
                }
              },
              axisLabel: {
                distance: -20,
                color: '#999',
                fontSize: 10
              },
              anchor: {
                show: true,
                showAbove: true,
                size: 12,
                itemStyle: {
                  borderWidth:0,
                  color: 'rgba(36,177, 76)',
                }
              },
              pointer: {
                icon: 'path://M2.9,0.7L2.9,0.7c1.4,0,2.6,1.2,2.6,2.6v115c0,1.4-1.2,2.6-2.6,2.6l0,0c-1.4,0-2.6-1.2-2.6-2.6V3.3C0.3,1.9,1.4,0.7,2.9,0.7z',
                width: 5,
                length: '60%',
                offsetCenter: [0, '8%'],
                itemStyle: {
                  color: 'rgba(36,177, 76)'
                }
              },


                title: {
                color: 'rgba(36,177, 76)',
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: 800,
                fontFamily: 'Arial',
                offsetCenter: [0, '100%']
              },

              detail: {
                valueAnimation: true,
                fontSize: 12,
                offsetCenter: [0, '55%'],
                show: true

              },
              data:gaugeData
            }
          ]
        };

        return option;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.init(this);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
    }

    attributeChangedCallback() {
    }

    clone(origin, target) {
        var target = target || {};
        for(var prop in origin) {
            target[prop] = origin[prop];
        }
    }

}

window.customElements.define('dw-meter', dwMeter);
```

Comment: Could you please also share the contents of `dwmeter.webcomponent.js`?

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you exactly you mean by changing the tag in step 5. Do you only change the value of the `@Tag` annotation on the `DwMeter` class, or are you also making other changes?

Comment: dwmeter.webcomponent.js:

Comment: 1. File dwmeter.webcomponent.js couldn't be pasted for large size, please find in the answer thread.
2. not @Tag annotation,  change web page element:
<dw-meter>...</dw-meter>   -> <div>...</div> please refer to  the attached screenshot of step 5

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70843587/edit) the question.  Comments are not meant for that. If the fie is large, put the relevant parts in.

Comment: Thank you Cfrick, I modified the question.

Comment: What do you mean *visualize*?

Answer (score 2):

The reason that nothing is shown when you're using the `<dw-meter>` custom element is that it has a shadow root, while the actual content (rendered by the ECharts library) is outside that shadow root. Whenever an element has a shadow root, then the content of the shadow root will be rendered and the content outside the shadow root will be rendered in the location of a `<slot>` element inside the shadow root. If there is no `<slot>`, then it won't be shown anywhere at all.

If you want to use the shadow root to encapsulate styles, then you would at the very least need to change `ECharts.init(o)` to instead do `ECharts.init(container)`. There might also be other things that you need to change to make it work properly, but that depends on exactly how ECharts is implemented. The `o` parameter that I assume you're passing from the server is most likely redundant since `this` is already a reference to the top-level element.

Comment: I tried ECharts.init(container), it also doesn't work. ECharts.init(param) can generate html elements for a meter, no matter the 'param' is an element object of div, slot or dw-meter. It's helpful if you could provide some web URL references.

Comment: Doesn't work in what way?